# Equivalent of **summation** in non metraizable topology

Tags: general-topology, summation, metric-spaces

If $X$ is a metric space and $d$ is the metric s.t $d: X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ then a finite sum like $\sum_{k=1}^n d(a,x_k)$ for a fixed $a\in X$ is a valid equation. But we know that this kind of summation is not defined in an arbitrary non-metrizable topology. Disjoint union in topology comes closest to summation.So can I write something like $$\bigcup_{k=1}^nU(a,x_k) $$ where $U(a,x_k)$ is a nbd of $a$ that contains $x_k$  too.But such an union can be indefinitely large, the whole space infact but that I do not want; I want this union of nbd's as small as possible. How do I ensure that?

Thank you.

Comment: Note: $\sum_{k=1}^nd(a,x_k)$ is a meaningful *expression*; it isn’t an *equation* at all. It’s not really clear what you want. In a metric space it’s possible to have points $a$ and $x$ such that if $x\in B(a,\epsilon)$, then $B(a,\epsilon)$ is the whole space, so this outcome can’t necessarily be avoided even in metric spaces.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: **as small as possible**-if it takes the whole space then I can do nothing but when there is a possibility that some nbd smaller than the whole space will suffice , I want to find the smallest such nbd . Is that possible ?

Comment: In general it’s not even possible to find the smallest nbhd of $a$ containing all of the $x_k$ even in a metric space; the best you can do is find $r>0$ such that $B(a,s)$ contains all of the $x_k$ if and only if $s>r$. In general topological spaces there is no analogue even of that.